# Absolute value definition

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Is it true that $\dots$
$$
\left| y \right| = 
\begin{cases}
   y \hspace{1cm} y \geq 0 \\ -y \hspace{0.7cm} y < 0
\end{cases}
$$

I'm a little bit confused with the second case, where $|y| = -y$ then $y<0$, 
for example :
$$
\left| 2x-4 \right|=-(2x-4)
$$
if we assume that $ y=2x-4 $ then 
$$
\begin{align*}
y&<0 \\
2x-4&<0 \\
2x&<4 \\
x&<2
\end{align*}
$$
in the other way, we can solve it like this
$$
\begin{align*}
|y| \geq 0 \\
|2x-4| \geq 0 \\
-(2x-4) \geq 0 \\
2x-4 \leq 0 \\
x \leq 2
\end{align*}
$$

why is it giving the different answers?

Comment: If you know $x<0$, $|x|>0$. Also, @your 2nd sentence, if $|x|=-x$, you know $x \leq 0$ (not necessarily $x<0$, since $x=0$ does satisfy $|x|=-x$).

Comment: warning $ax-b<0\iff ax<b$ you wrote $ax<-b$ (think of it as adding $b$ both sides)

Comment: i'm sorry for that @zwim

Comment: @Useless many references said like that , http://images.slideplayer.com/25/7667598/slides/slide_9.jpg

Comment: "Is it true that ...". Yes, this is the definition.

Comment: hmm... what are you trying to solve?

Comment: @HansenFrenico $|x| = -x$ would implies $x \leq 0$. That picture doesn't say this. But $x < 0$ implies $|x| = -x$ instead.

Comment: @Azlif thanks , i understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should train to read formulas without reference to specific variables. The definition
$$
|x|=\begin{cases}
x & x\ge0 \\[4px]
-x & x<0
\end{cases}
$$
it is meant that

> the absolute value of a number is
>
> 1. the number itself if it is greater than or equal to $0$,
> 2. the negative of the number if it is less than $0$.

You should also avoid using a variable with two different meanings in the same statement.

It seems that you want to see when $|2x-4|=-(2x-4)$. According to the definition, this happens if and only if

1. $2x-4<0$, or
2. $2x-4=0$.

Why the second case? Because $0=-0$. On the other hand, if $2x-4>0$, then we cannot have $(2x-4)=-(2x-4)$, because one term is positive and the other one is negative.

One might make the initial definition more symmetric by declaring
$$
|x|=\begin{cases}
x & x>0 \\[4px]
0 & x=0 \\[4px]
-x & x<0
\end{cases}
$$
but you can also note that
$$
|x|=\begin{cases}
x & x>0 \\[4px]
-x & x\le0
\end{cases}
$$
would be a completely equivalent definition.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in general the definition is

$$\left| f(x) \right| = 
\begin{cases}
   f(x) \hspace{1cm} f(x) \geq 0 \\ -f(x)  \hspace{0.7cm} f(x) < 0
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

The absolute value make a function simmetrical with respect to the $x$-axis.
Then we have pay attention when the function assumes negative value.
In your example we have:

$$|2x−4|=\begin{cases}2x-4 \quad\text{if} \quad 2x-4\ge0\implies x\ge2\\
4-2x\quad \text{if} \quad 2x-4 <0\implies x<2\end{cases}$$

The graphic of your function in fact is:

$\hspace{6cm}$[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit confusing to use the same letter $x$ for your substitution.

Let set $y=2x-4$.

Then $|y|$ is $\begin{cases}+y&=2x-4&\quad\text{when}\quad y\ge0\iff 2x-4\ge 0\iff x\ge 2\\-y&=4-2x&\quad\text{when}\quad y<0\iff 2x-4<0\iff x<2\end{cases}$

Indeed for $x=1$ then $x<2$ then $|y|=|2\times 1-4|=|-2|=2=4-2\times 1$

And for $x=3$ then $x\ge 2$ then $|y|=|2\times 3-4|=|2|=2=2\times 3-4$

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but why $x<2$ and not $x \leq 2$? $|2 \times 2-4| = 4-2 \times 2$

Comment: Both are valid since $+0=-0=0$. I just copy/pasted you own definition of $|y|$ where you said $|y|=-y$ when $y<0$, but $y\le 0$ also works.